# Удаление файлов php

Tags: php

Когда делается бэкап сайта, нужно чтобы скрипт перебирал все файлы, удалял все "порченые" и, если количество файлов больше чем 3, то оставлял только самые новые.
Пример имен файлов(нормальные и с ошибками):

> 21.01.16-18.46.zip
>   19.01.16-14.38.zip
>   21.01.16-18.43.zip.owTd3N
>   10.01.16-19.18.zip
>   21.01.16-18.04.zip.BFcjCL

Я получаю массив с именами файлов, а вот как их отсортировать и удалить - я не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

```
$dir="./backup/";
$files_arr=array();
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(filetype($dir . $file)=='file'){
                array_push($files_arr , $file);
//                print "Файл: $file : тип: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
            }}
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Comment: Определение "Порченые" дайте.

Comment: после .zip имеется еще что-то.  
пример 21.01.16-18.43.zip.owTd3N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:
Добавьте вот в конец:

```
$timeSorted = Array(); //здесь будем хранить не "битые" файлы и их даты создания
foreach($files_arr as $file) { 
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // вытягиваем расширения
    if (strToLower($ext)!='zip') { // не zip - стираем
        unlink($dir . $file);
    } else { // емсли бэкап не битый - сохраняем дату создания
        $timeSorted[$file] = fileсtime($dir . $file);
    }
}
arsort($timeSorted);// сортируем по дате создания
if (Count($timeSorted)>2) { //если файлов больше 2-x
    $files = array_keys($timeSorted); // используем только имена файлов
    for ($i=3; $i<=Count($files); $i++) { // прокручиваем и стираем все, что больше 2-х
        unlink($dir . $files[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: С http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php можно немного изящнее сделать но суть такая же останется.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло.